# Passing array data from view to controller and reverse php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I am trying to pass the data from view to controller using php codeigniter. Here is my form view:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url()?>downloadfiles">
    <p>Download file</p>                    
    <p>Browse zip file</p> 
    <input type="text" name="data" value="<?= $data; ?>" style="display: none">                                     
    <input type="submit" name="downloadfiles" value="Download" />
</form>
```

And in downloadfiles.php - the controller, I try to get the array $data passing by POST method and passing it back to the download_success.php view:

```
if ($this->input->post('downloadfiles')) {
        $data = $_POST['data'];          
        $this->load->view('upload/download_success', $data);
    }
```

This is my code in download_success.php:

```
<?php                
    if(!empty($data))
    {
       print_r($data);
    }
?>
```

When I run the code in the form view, it returns the error array to string conversion, and in the download_success view, it didn't print anything. Where were I wrong?

Comment: In your controller replace `$data = $_POST['data'];` `with $data = array('my_data' => $_POST['data'] );` and in view replace `$data` with '$my_data'

Comment: I did and it returned the same error.

Comment: I have updated the script in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are passing a string variable with the view and CodeIgniter consider it as an array.

MyController.php

```
if ($this->input->post('downloadfiles')) {
    $view_data = array('my_data' => $this->input->post('data') );          
    $this->load->view('upload/download_success', $view_data);
}
```

my_view.php

```
if(!empty($my_data))
{
   print_r($my_data);
}
```

Your form will be like:

//if $my_data is an array then you can print_r($my_data) and show the required values you want to show in your view.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url()?>downloadfiles">
    <p>Download file</p>                    
    <p>Browse zip file</p> 
    <input type="text" name="data" value="<?=$my_data?>">                                     
    <input type="submit" name="downloadfiles" value="Download" />
</form>
```

Try this and I hope it will help you.

Comment: I also printed $my_data array in my form to test the data in the array. It printed correctly. But in my_view.php it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Hey updated is the code I have executed at my local system but it's not giving me this error.

Comment: Ok, are you getting an error or just empty `$my_data` ?

Comment: it just return empty $my_data.

Comment: In your form you make the input field hidden so how are you passing the value in it then?

Comment: The form is not supposed to get input from user, I already had the array $my_data and set the form value as $my_data and want to get the array in my_view.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155049/discussion-between-harish-and-tedxxxx).

Comment: Thanks. Accepted it.